# node.js winston logger no colors with nohup

Tags: node.js, logging, nohup, winston

We are using winston logger in our project with the following transport settings:

```
file: {
            filename: __base + '/log/server.log',
            colorize : true,
            timestamp : true,
            json : false,
            prettyPrint : true
        }
```

If the application is started with nohup, log file is not colorized. It works only without nohup.

```
nohup supervisor -w . -i node_modules/ server.js &
```

Is it problem with winston or nohup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's caused by [colors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/colors) package (used by `winston`) that performs the [following check](https://github.com/Marak/colors.js/blob/master/lib/system/supports-colors.js#L40) when trying to determine whether to support colors:

```
if (process.stdout && !process.stdout.isTTY) {
    return false;
}
```

This means that when your application is running in a background, it doesn't have a terminal and colors are not used. This affects commands/apps other than `nohup` as well (see [issue #121](https://github.com/Marak/colors.js/issues/121)).

A simple workaround is to start your application with `--color=true` argument (or to simulate it with `process.argv.push('--color=true')` before `require('winston')` is called.

Alternatively, you can patch `winston` - just add one line to [lib/winston/config.js](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/blob/master/lib/winston/config.js#L10):

```
var colors = require('colors/safe');
colors.enabled = true; // add this line
```

However, all of these workarounds will most likely make the console logger to use colors even when there is no terminal.